# Why is the German version of Prometheus released 2 months after the world premiere?

Tags: prometheus, film-industry

Usually Big Blockbusters are timed to be released in major countries at roughly the same time. This even includes movies that are dubbed for localised version.

The [London premiere was on 31 May 2012](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1446714/releaseinfo) but the German release will be on 9 August 2012.

Is there any information why the German version got a 2 month delay?

Comment: The reason would be Euro-2012.They would be premiered on 8th June as they are premiered in most countries including USA.But the  Euro 2012 starts the same day.

Comment: @VijinPaulraj - that does not make that much sense as most of Europe is going to be interested in Euro-2012, including the UK.  Italy isn't seeing the movie until *mid-October* !!!

Comment: @iandotkelly,I guess that would be a reason.Anyway..I'm lucky to watch the movie by tomorrow:)

Comment: Plus it gives them a couple of months to write a new script and re-edit the film. I jest of course ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like Vijin was right. I asked [@foxdeutschland](https://twitter.com/foxdeutschland) about this and they responded:

[image]

This roughly translates to:

> **oers**: Why is Prometheus released here [in germany] two month after the
> world premiere?
>
> **fox**: The german release had to be postponed due to the
> UEFA Euro 2012 to august.